# Pass value from output of one command to sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file, config.txt with many lines. One line is like this

```
address=
```

I am getting the ip address of the machine on which config.txt resides, with

```
ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/'
```

That  code is taken from a Stack Overflow answer.. The output I am getting is an IP address -

```
192.168.3.260
```

I would like to replace

```
address=
```

in config.txt with

```
address='192.168.3.260'
```

Is it possible to do it in one line, i.e.

```
ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/' | <some sed command >
```

Comment: can you show the current value which gives you the above command?

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: try `sed "s/address=/&$(ifconfig eth0|grep -oP 'inet addr:\K[^ ]+')/g"`

Comment: or `sed "s/address=/&$(hostname -I)/g"`

Comment: there's no `address= ` within your output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/address=/address='$(ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/')'/' filename
```

Where filename is the name of the file in question, the key here is to use indirection i.e. $(ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/') and then use this in a sed command placing particular emphasis on the quotation marks. The indirection must side outside of the single quotation marks of the sed command.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`, `cut` and `awk` in a single pipeline is almost always a mistake, since `awk` can do everything `grep` can do, and then some. You can extract the IP address with a `sed` one-liner, like this:

```
ip addr | sed -n '/state UP/ {n;n;s/ *inet \(.*\)\/.*/\1/p}'
```

You can also use this approach to build the command you are looking for:

```
ip addr | sed -n "/state UP/ {n;n;s/ *inet \(.*\)\/.*/s|address=|\&'\1'|/p}"
```

which prints something like this:

```
s|address=|&'192.168.3.260'|
```

And then you can pipe that program to `sed`:

```
ip addr | sed -n "/state UP/ {n;n;s/ *inet \(.*\)\/.*/s|address=|\&'\1'|/p}" \
   | sed -f - config.txt
```